# Use Google Chrome DevTools to click on the "Follow" buttons on the page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

[image]

My current script:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.components-button components-button-size-mini components-button-type-orange desktop components-button-inline').forEach(btn => btn.click());
```

I am not able to understand why it is not working, until last week everything was ok when I sent the script and hit enter the buttons were clicked, now this is not happening anymore.

What do I need to adjust to make it work?

Link to Site:
https://booyah.live/users/42973126/followers

Comment: Have you tried without the foreach to see if the selector is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to target an element that contains all the classes you specified, you need to separate the class names with a dot. For example:

```
<div class="my-class another-class" />

document.querySelector('.my-class.another-class')
```

What you have is some element with the class `.components-button` that contains another element with element name `components-button-size-mini` that contains another element with name `components-button-type-orange` and so on. Of course in this example I don't think you have an actual element with such names.

So to fix your code, follow the pattern I presented above for the selector string:

```
.some-class.another-class.yet-another-class
```

The above will target elements with the three classes as specified: `some-class`, `another-class`, and `yet-another-class`